# Can testcafe connect to a Smart TV development deployed app?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, smart-tv

I'm evaluating whether testcafe can be driven inside an embedded app, for instance, a Tizen or WebOS Smart TV.

By creating a runner and browser connection one can make the app be fully controlled by navigating to the remoteConnection URL. [1]. But that's replacing the app itself. I'd rather pass on control via insert a script tag to the app's HTML page. Is this scenario possible (even only a subset of features would be exposed?)

[1] http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/programming-interface/testcafe.html#createbrowserconnection

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "replacing the app itself" and the behavior you expect. Would you please clarify this?